# Can I use Salesforce Community Cloud as an Identity Provider for SAML SSO into my Application?

Tags: salesforce, saml, salesforce-communities

Our SaaS application supports SAML SSO as a service provider. As such we can use Salesforce as the Identity Provider, and either have a link to our application or a webtab displaying our application in Salesforce.

Some customers have Salesforce Community Cloud, and they want to have SSO set up for their community into our application. Can Salesforce Community Cloud act as a SAML Identity Provider for out application?

Comment: Yes: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257274/salesforce-as-identity-provider-for-third-party-applications-how-to-extend-it-f